# Could not read from remote repository. SwiftyDropbox

Tags: ios, xcode, git, macos, ssh

I created ssh key and added it to github. But when I launch `$ ssh -vT git@github.com` I got the error **Permission denied (publickey)**. I tried several different methods but I got the same error. Still I want to add SwiftyDropbox to my project but I get **Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.** But I all made by order. I don't know what do I do? Please help me.

```
    I make following for install SwiftyDropbox
    MacBook-Pro:~ Alexsander$ cd Desktop
    MacBook-Pro:Desktop Alexsander$ cd Apple
    MacBook-Pro:Apple Alexsander$ cd Development
    MacBook-Pro:Development Alexsander$ cd TestCocao
    MacBook-Pro:TestCocao Alexsander$ cd PodsTest
    MacBook-Pro:PodsTest Alexsander$ pod setup
    Setting up CocoaPods master repo
Setup completed
MacBook-Pro:PodsTest Alexsander$ touch Podfile
MacBook-Pro:PodsTest Alexsander$ open Podfile
MacBook-Pro:PodsTest Alexsander$ pod install
Updating local specs repositories
[!] Error installing SwiftyDropbox
[!] /usr/bin/git clone git@github.com:dropbox/SwiftyDropbox.git /var/folders/vl/6w14j04s5n11cgfcrgwdql940000gn/T/d20151002-1479-17ri6hu --single-branch --depth 1 --branch 0.4

Cloning into '/var/folders/vl/6w14j04s5n11cgfcrgwdql940000gn/T/d20151002-1479-17ri6hu'...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After create a new ssh key and I added it in my github account, it is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you already have an ssh key https://docs.github.com/es/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/checking-for-existing-ssh-keys

If you don't, create a new one. https://docs.github.com/es/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent

Then add it to yout Github https://docs.github.com/es/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account